# Pod volumes merged directory symlink

Tags: kubernetes

I have this kind of files tree:

- /root

  - /child1

    - file1
    - file2
  - /child2

    - file3

I'm trying to create a volume mount for a pod (into a k8s job) with this files tree:

- /shared

  - file1
  - file2
  - file3

There is a lot of files so I don't want to copy it into temporary files

Is it possible to do that with the Pod configuration or do I need to create temporary symlinks on the host machine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your pod only needs access to /shared.

creating symbolic links on the host might work but than you need access to the host kubernetes is running on.

Another approach can be to add an initcontainer to your pod and mount both /root and /shared to that container and use the initcontainer to create the symbolic links.

Comment: Brillant idea the init container! Thanks!